# Better way to create an admin screen

Tags: admin, liferay

my requirement is to create an admin screen in liferay. 
The admin will have options to show/hide fields and set mandatory (y/n).
I dont want to a large page with all the dropdowns to select each and every field.

I was thinking how about grouping all 'view' fields together.

Can anybody give me some idea. (Basically I want to make it look short and sweet :P )

Comment: Hi simplysiby, this looks more like a ui\ux question and there is a [StackExchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) for that. You might have better luck there.

Answer (score 0):

For the "admin screen" itself it sounds like you want a portlet's "edit" mode. Alternatively you might want to configure a portlet to appear in the control panel.

If the question is more directed on how to actually develop the interface, this is standard portlet development - I'd need some more information about the intent then.